# Do I use remained or quite to be changed by an adverb?

Tags: etymology

Here is my homework question. He remained quite still. Is remained or quite changed by the adverb?

Comment: "Quite" is the adverb, and cannot "change" itself.

Answer (score 1):

*Quite* modifies *still*.

From [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/156796?rskey=FRO6g0&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid):

> A. adv.
>   I. As an intensifier: completely, fully, entirely; to the utmost extent or degree.

This sentence means that "He remained still to the fullest extent possible."

Answer (score 1):

Your question makes an incorrect assumption about what the adverb in the sentence is.

**He** is a *pronoun*.
**Remained** is a *verb*.
**Quite** is the *adverb*: it modifies **still**.
**Still** is an *adjective*: it modifies **he**.

"The adverb" modifies neither **remained** (the verb) nor **quite** (itself).